# Best recordings of 2013

Tags: field-recording, fun, recordings

Its that time again.

Let's post our favorite recordings from 2013.

My first contribution is of my newborn baby boy - Caruso.  He's pretty awesome.

[image: Baby C]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Rcoronado's baby, here's mine (who's almost 1 year now). This was recorded around his 4th month, and composed somewhere in the following 2 months. It was indeed very badly recorded (an iPhone at more or less 1,5 meters distance) but I enjoyed the composing around the original sounds.

https://soundcloud.com/soundsrealproductions/little-dr-l-dreams-i-between

Answer (score 1):

Oh, a nice idea.
I fear my favorite recording of the year is on the creepy side, too ...

a whistling scaffolding in rural Sweden, nice eerie tubes. Quite a classic thing to record indeed, but the crowd of ducks that were having fun around the place give the recording this bizarre feel !
https://soundcloud.com/felixdavin/whistling-scaffolding

Happy new year !

Comment: that's a nice one.  lots of low end and creepiness.  what was the setup?

Comment: There are 2x dpa 4060s in a Mixpre-D, going into a PCM-M10. My usual holiday setup, light and comfy ! (and Congrats on your child ! )

Answer (score 0):

Great idea!

My favourite is this one: http://deauditievedienst.tumblr.com/post/66100351759/a-mysterious-sound

Happy holidays!

Arnoud

Comment: Wow, that was creepy!

Comment: yeah i thought the cuteness overload should get some competition from the dark side ;) happpy new year with caruso and the family!!